# Origins Destinations Excel VBA API (Google Maps)

Tags: excel, vba, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to find the distance and travel time between multiple origins and destinations. For some reason, my code does not work at all. There are no errors, i just have nothing as output. See the attached Image for Excel worksheet.

```
Sub Origins_Destinations()
    Dim a, b, i, Str As String
    Dim lineS As Variant

    On Error Resume Next
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest")
        Dim iRow As Long: iRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("g65000").End(xlUp).Row
        For j = 4 To iRow
            b = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("b4" & j)
            a = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("a4" & j)
            .Open "GET", "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=" & a & " &destinations= " & b & " &key=MY_KEY", False
            .Send
            lineS = Split(.ResponseText, vbLf)
            For k = 25 To UBound(lineS)
                If Trim(lineS(k)) = """distance"" : {" Then
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next k
             ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("c" & j) = lineS(k + 1)
             ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("d" & j) = lineS(k + 5)
             Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        Next j
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True    
End Sub
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHmK6.png)

Any suggestions ?????

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please take a moment to check out the [Tour] as well as [ask] and **important tips in [mcve]**.  I'm been working with the Google Maps API's lately, and I have a function for calculating distance between points, but the first thing we'll need is some sample **Data**.  The code isn't very helpful without knowing more about what's in the cells that it's looking at....  Also, I assume that when you replaced `My API Key` with your _actual_ Google Maps API Key before running the code, right?

Comment: ...also, at first glance I see some simple mistakes like: **`"&mode=walking&key=walking&key=MY API Kew"**'.  That's obviously not right.  Have you looked over the code yourself?  Perhaps tried getting a fresh copy of the code from the google website and starting over on building the URL?

Comment: ...last suggestion until you figure out [ask] a question in such a way that others are able to help you:  Why don't you start with getting the URL working in your browser before you attempt to parse it programmatically.  For example, you would paste the string `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=____ &destinations=____ &mode=walking&key=walking&key=MY API Kew` into your browser's address bar -- **after** you figure out what you're missing far like data, key, it's probably not supposed to have spaces, etc.  Google's Maps API Developer website has a ton of info.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I have changed the url but still i have no output. Also, i did check the URL + API through putting it in my browser and it worked well.

Comment: No, but I live in BC. It was just an Example :)

Comment: Too bad, if it WAS Transit data, I'd have a solution ready to go for you (more accurate their their stupid website, lol)....  okay well now you're on my good side for being local. :-)   SO , you have the URL loading the JSON data correct in your browser now, right?

Comment: **You have output LIKE THIS?:** destination_addresses 
0 "1555 Banks Rd, Kelowna, BC V1X 7Y8, Canada"
origin_addresses 
0 "3333 University Way, Kelowna, BC V1V 1V7, Canada"
rows 
0 
elements 
0 
distance 
text "4.9 mi"
value 7901
duration 
text "11 mins"
value 677
status "OK"
status "OK"   ...and you want to retrieve **Distance.Text** and **Duration.Text** via VBA, is that right?

Comment: Well, you keep disappearing and I'm pretty much out of time but I'll going out on a limb with a guess of what you're looking for.  See the answer.

Comment: Sorry for that. Yes, exactly

Comment: by the way, one of the reasons you couldn't troubleshoot your original code is because it's ignoring errors.   Until an application is functioning properly, you should remove `On Error Resume Next` and add `Option Explicit` at the top, and you will be a lot more likely find where the problems lay.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I understand, the code below is what you're looking for to get you started.  Enter your Google Maps API Key in the Constant at the top, and then run sub `TestRun`.

It will replace disallowed characters in the address you provided, then loads the JSON results from Google Matrix into a string, and then, since we're only looking for 1 or 2 values, it will use a messy cheater-method to location the values, that I can't guarantee will always work:

It finds the first occurrence of the word "distance", and then the first occurrence of the word "value" after that, move 3 more characters to the right, and then take whatever is between there and the next " " blank space, and converts it to a value, hopefully the **distance in meters**.

Then it repeats (from beginning of file) to find **"duration" in seconds**, the same method.  Note that the distance and duration are being returned to variables "byref".

As I said, it's very convoluted, but you get what you pay for.  (Normally I wouldn't share code this "yucky", but you're in my neighborhood, so, Go Canada!)

```
Option Explicit
'3333 University Way,Kelowna,BC,V1V 1V7
'1555 Banks Rd, Kelowna, BC, V1X 7Y8
'1938 Pandosy Street, Kelowna, BC, V1Y 1R7
'2280 Baron Rd, Kelowna, BC, V1X 7W3
Const key = "YOUR-API-KEY-HERE"


Sub testRun()

    Dim orig As String, dest As String, distance_Meters As Long, duration_Sec As Long
    orig = EncodeEscapeString("3333 University Way,Kelowna,BC,V1V 1V7")
    dest = EncodeEscapeString("1555 Banks Rd, Kelowna, BC, V1X 7Y8")

    Call getGoogleDistanceMatrix(orig, dest, distance_Meters, duration_Sec)

    Debug.Print distance_Meters & "m"
    Debug.Print duration_Sec & "sec"

End Sub


Sub getGoogleDistanceMatrix(ByVal orig As String, ByVal dest As String, ByRef distance_Meters As Long, ByRef duration_Sec As Long)

    Const distanceTag1 = """distance"""
    Const distanceTag2 = """value"""
    Const durationTag1 = """duration"""
    Const durationTag2 = """value"""

    Dim jSON As String, pStart As Long, pEnd As Long
    jSON = Get_URL_text("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&origins=" & orig & "&destinations=" & dest & "&key=" & key)

    pStart = InStr(jSON, distanceTag1) + Len(distanceTag1)
    pStart = InStr(pStart, jSON, distanceTag2) + Len(distanceTag2) + 3
    pEnd = InStr(pStart, jSON, " ")
    distance_Meters = Val(Trim(Mid(jSON, pStart, pEnd - pStart)))

    pStart = InStr(jSON, durationTag1) + Len(durationTag1)
    pStart = InStr(pStart, jSON, durationTag2) + Len(durationTag2) + 3
    pEnd = InStr(pStart, jSON, " ")
    duration_Sec = Val(Trim(Mid(jSON, pStart, pEnd - pStart)))

End Sub

Function Get_URL_text(url As String) As String

    Dim XMLHTTP As Object
    Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
    XMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
    XMLHTTP.send
    Get_URL_text = XMLHTTP.responseText
    Set XMLHTTP = Nothing

End Function

Function EncodeEscapeString(str_In As String) As String

    Dim s As String

    s = str_In
    s = Replace(s, "%", "%25")
    s = Replace(s, " ", "%20")
    s = Replace(s, Chr(34), "%22")
    s = Replace(s, "<", "%3C")
    s = Replace(s, ">", "%3E")
    s = Replace(s, "#", "%23")
    s = Replace(s, "|", "%7C")

    EncodeEscapeString = s

End Function
```

This same "cheater method" can be used to to scrape bits of data from any URL (JSON, HTML, XML, CSV, etc) that has a consistent text output.

You may need to add a Tools -> Reference to support XMLHTTP.

**Good luck with that!**  (and don't forget to "accept" this answer if it's at all useful, I already put more time into this than I intended!)

Comment: Many Thanks, Go Canada :)

Comment: The main purpose of the tool is to automate the process of getting the distances and travel times between origins and destinations. I think the problem is in the ActiveX thing. I do not how to fix it.